# Why my subdomains are ranking really high.

Tags: seo, subdomain

I have a site with many users. Lets say my site is called `thecommunity.com`.

For each of my users I give them a free url such as `jason.thecommunity.com` or `susan.thecommunity.com`

These subdomains really just render their thecommunity.com profile page. I use wildcards in dns and all *.thecommunity.com requests are sent to the main domain. In the main domain I look at the request and if there is a subdomain I just render their profile page. So `jason.thecommunity.com` looks exactly like `thecommunity.com/jason`

When you are at `jason.thecommunity.com` you can still click around the full site but your clicking around using the `jason.thecommunity.com` subdomain, accessing pages that are also available on `thecommunity.com`

This created thousands of subdomains. Any many of them are suddenly ranking very high in search results. For instance a search for `soup recipe` might have `jason.thecommunity.com/soups/recipe`as the top result!

But `thecommunity.com/soups/recipe` is not even in the first say 100 pages of results. My traffic has increased x 5 which is a pretty big number. Most of this search traffic is coming into my subdomains vs the main site.

Any reason for this?

Comment: Because some of your users are creating great content?

Comment: ... and the subdomains are being linked to/shared. Are you not canonicalising the URLs? It looks like you should at least be setting a `rel="canonical"` to your apex domain if the content is available on both. Otherwise you could find that just one or two "user" subdomains might take over!?

Comment: Yes, @MichaelHampton the content is great I feel. It's just so odd that these subdomains are getting the traffic as opposed to the main domain. `jason.thecomminity.com` looks exactly like `thecomminity.com` with the one single exception that `jason.thecommunity.com` renders his profile page because of a single conditional that checks for a subdomain and renders their profile page instead of `thecommunity.com` homepage.

Comment: @w3dk I really don't think the subdomains are being shared much to be honest. But I will have to look into `rel="canonical"` as I do nothing like this and am not sure what it even means. I want to be careful to not mess up all this traffic I am getting!

Answer (score 2):

To summarise the comments from @Michael Hampton and @w3dk:

Your users are providing great content (like the soup recipe) and it's gaining backlinks, traffic, and visibility.

You should be adding a rel=canonical tag to your page headers that is a cross-domain suggestion that Google index another address for the content. When it's indexing the page on your domain, you domain gains equity rather than the subdomain (which is seen as a different site to Google).

Comment: I'm honestly just scared that that this could mess up my rankings. I am very thoughtful about designing for SEO but I just can't be sure if recent work on SEO optimization is responsible for this traffic or if somehow this change in architecture is doing something. I don't want to lose the traffic! Really once someone browses off the profile page of `jason.thecommunity.com` the url should switch to `thecommunity.com` I can fix that but not sure I want too...

Comment: You can either 301 redirect (which changes the request URI and therefore what is indexed) or you can canonicalise (which Google can optionally ignore but generally is good about).

In your position, I would canonicalise. The content may vary and is spread out across many different domains - however, having one large powerful domain is likely to increase it's worth.

Comment: Thats the thing. The content does not vary. Not at all. All of the subdomains look like the root domain. Exactly. Except for 1 thing. When a user visits the root of `jason.thecommunity.com` they are shown the profile page of `jason`. When a user visits the root of `thecommunity.com` they are shown the root page of the entire site. That is the only difference.

Comment: Are they only profiles, no extra content? Because that's where the value is. If they're generic and repetitive then keep them as is and don't move them on domain.

Comment: No there is no extra content on all of the subdomains. The subdomains look exactly like the main domain except that the subdomain will show the users profile when you hit the subdomain root.

Comment: Then you'll want to go the canonical tag route. It tells Google the content is all (nearly) identical despite the domain being different.This will aggregate all the equity onto your main domain. You'll want to add rel=canonical for every single template to make sure it maps correctly, not just the home page.

Comment: Thank you @Yhorian. I still contemplate this. When all the equity on each page is aggregated to the main domain do you think this will effectively help my overall SEO? As I have stated often the content on ALL these subdomains is exactly the same as the main domain. The only thing with these subdomains is jason.thecommunity.com renders jasons profile page but once you start clicking around on that subdomain everything is the same as the main domain except of course every page has the subdomain prefix. e.g. jason.thecomminity.com/all-users looks exactly the same as thecommunity.com/all-users.